# Convertir fechas a estaciones

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una lista de fechas que he extraido de una tabla:

```
      piezas_vendidos = [ ]          
      for i in Piezas.select(Piezas.Fecha_fabricacion_piezas):    
               piezas_vendidos.append(i.Fecha_fabricacion_piezas)
      print(piezas_vendidos)

      ['25/01/2020 12:17:22', '25/01/2020 12:17:22', '25/07/2020 12:17:22']
```

Me gustaría sustituir la fecha entera por la estación del año que le corresponde.
¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: @AdrianPL El título de la pregunta no ayuda a entender el problema que se está intentando resolver. Es importante poner títulos más precisos, para faclitar que esta pregunta sea encontrada por otros usuarios que tengan un problema similar. La puedes editar para tiularla algo como "Convertir fechas a estaciones" o similar? No hace falta poner python en el título, pues ya está en las etiquetas.

Comment: Perfecto @abulafia ahora mismo lo cambio

Comment: Muchas gracias. He quitado también la etiqueta sql, que no es relevante, pues aunque las fechas salgan de una base de datos en este caso, el problema es más genérico y requiere sólo python estándar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución, adaptada de [esta respuesta en SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139306/determine-season-given-timestamp-in-python-using-datetime) y simplificada para mejorar la legibilidad, podría ser como sigue:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime

Y = 2020 # año bisiesto arbitrario, por si la fecha es un 29 de febrero
estaciones = [('invierno', date(Y,  1,  1),  date(Y,  3, 20)),
              ('primavera', date(Y,  3, 21),  date(Y,  6, 20)),
              ('verano', date(Y,  6, 21),  date(Y,  9, 22)),
              ('otoño', date(Y,  9, 23),  date(Y, 12, 20)),
              ('invierno', date(Y, 12, 21),  date(Y, 12, 31))]

def get_season(fecha):
    for estacion, inicio, fin in estaciones:
      if inicio <= fecha <= fin:
        return estacion
```

Esa función va recorriendo las fechas de inicio y fin de cada estación y se detiene cuando el día suministrado está comprendido entre esas fechas, retornando el nombre de la estación.

La función requiere que el parámetro que le pasas sea de tipo `date`. En tu caso lo que tienes son cadenas de caracteres por lo que deberás convertirlas antes a un objeto de tipo `date`, mediante `datetime.strptime().date()`. A esta función debes además especificarle un formato que indique cómo está estructurada tu cadena (qué parte es el día, cuál el mes, el año, etc..) En este caso la cadena de formato sería:

```
formato = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Ahora podemos iterar sobre tu lista, convirtiendo cada elemento a un `date`, que le pasamos a la función `get_season()` y recogemos su resultado para ir creando otra lista con esos resultados. Con la sintaxis de *list comprehensions* esto se reduce a una línea:

```
resultado = [ get_season(datetime.strptime(fecha, formato).date) for fecha in fechas ]
```

Y el resultado obtenido (para las fechas `['25/01/2020 12:17:22', '25/01/2020 12:17:22', '25/07/2020 12:17:22']`) es:

```
['invierno', 'invierno', 'verano']
```

Comment: Sin palabras @abulafia , me parece tan increible la estrategia que hay detrás. Muchas gracias